How to Categorize BigQuery Jobs by Dataform Routine
I have a Jobs table (JOBS_BY_PROJECT from the INFORMATION_SCHEMA) in my BigQuery. I want to differentiate and categorize these Jobs based on the DataForm routine from which they were executed. Does anyone know how I can do this?
I tried to figure it out using the labels and Job execution ID, but it does not indicate the repository or DataForm workflow.

One thing to try is setting the @@query_label variable in your Dataform SQLX to a name/value pair.  When the BigQuery Job is submitted from Dataform, that should associate the label with the record in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.  You can then query the INFORMATION_SCHEMA table to filter by labels.

This is what I've always done - via pre_operations:
pre_operations {
SET @@query_label = "key:value"
}
